# How to get ui router's $state object from console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to change the route from console, and I've try this to get $state object:

```
$inject = angular.injector(['ng', 'ui.router']);
$inject.get('$state').go
```

but got error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $urlRouter <- $state <- $location(…)
```

the ui.router is included on the page. How can I get the $state object from console and change the router using $state.go('state');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change state using:

```
injector = angular.element($('body')).injector();
injector.get('$state').go('some-state');
```